# How many nodes/records can I have at the top level of an OpenLdap server

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have installed openLdap.
Created one top record/node and some others below that.
Can I create another top record?
I am trying to achieve the same effect of creating several DBs on one sql server (or may be I am missing the point on how this tool should be used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can create as many top records as you want. I'm assuming by top record you mean the top-most entry in a tree (such as `dc=serverfault,dc=com`).

There are two approaches to this:

1) Configure your server to hold several databases, one for each top record. Using slapd.conf, this is equivalent to adding blocks of a few lines like the following:

```
database hdb
suffix "dc=top,dc=record,dc=1"
... etc ...
```

Repeating as many times as you want top records.

2) Configure your server to hold only one database, using the suffix "" (empty string). This would ressemble the following statement in slapd.conf:

```
database hdb
suffix ""
... etc ...
```

Then you can add as many top records as you like.

Answer (score 0):

when you have different clients you can put multiple first nodes in your openldap, but when the different clients are only different organisational units you should create them as subnodes of one organisation.

do you have an example what types of first level nodes you want to create? perhaps this way you get some more precise answers.

Comment: One for development and one for me to play with and learn

Comment: this will be fine in one ldap server. but when you setup your qs and production environment you should think about single instances so you can test your changes in a more secure environment.